# Determine $a, b, c$ such that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^x{a + b\cos t+c\cos 2t}\,dt=\frac{1}{5}$

Tags: integration, limits

Determine $a, b, c$ such that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^5}\int_0^x{a + b\cos t+c\cos 2t}\,dt=\frac{1}{5}$$

I tried something. I realize the bounds are the same for the integral so regardless of the terms inside the integral will be equal to $0$. Then we apply L'hospital and the equality becomes:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{5x^4}(a+b\cos x + c\cos 2x) = \frac{1}{5}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(a+b\cos x + c\cos 2x)}{x^4} = 1$$
Now when I plug in $x = 0$ the limit will be equal to $\frac{a + b + c}{0}$ which is equal to $+/-\infty$ based on numerator's sign. This does not satisfy the equality. Do I need to assume $a + b + c = 0$ and keep applying L'hospitals or is this complete non-sense? I don't know I tried, help meeeee.

Comment: the limit is 1,you can get $a+b+c=0$,then  keep applying L'hospitals

Comment: Or, you can use Taylor expansion